# PDF'ing Workbook - Page numbers algined to PDF instead of Sheet

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, spreadsheet

I have a workbook with multiple sheets. Some sheets have more than 1 page, so I have the following in the footer `Page &[Page] of &[Pages]` to display the number of pages in each sheet.

I then PDF them using the code below:

```
Sub PDFSheets()
    Dim ans As Variant
    Dim fPath As String
    Dim Team As String
    ans = MsgBox("Please ensure the sheets you would like to PDF are visible before running this macro. Files will be saved to your Desktop." & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Do you wish to continue?", vbYesNo + vbInformation, "PDF Sheets")

    If ans = vbYes Then
        Sheets("FrontSheet").Visible = True
        Sheets("Launcher").Visible = False
        Team = Sheets("FrontSheet").Range("E21").Value
        fPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")
        Call SelectAllSheets
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=fPath & "/" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd") & Team & " VM", _
        openafterpublish:=True, ignoreprintareas:=False
        Sheets("Launcher").Visible = True
        Sheets("FrontSheet").Visible = False
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Example scenario:
-Sheet 1 has 1 page, no footer
-Sheet 2 has 5 pager, with the footer `Page &[Page] of &[Pages]`
- The PDF will then output `2 of 6` on the bottom of sheet 2

This is adhering to the rules of the PDF and not the page numbers in the sheet. Any ideas how I can get it to out put `1 of 5` instead (as shown on the workbook)?

Any help is appreciated
Calico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
With Worksheets("Launcher").PageSetup
    .RightFooter = "&""Arial""&10 Page &P of " & .Pages.Count       
End With
```

Also, go to Page Layout -> Page Setup, in the Page tab, set First page number to 1.

Comment: Hi Lisa,  thanks for the reply. Ah I see, Guessing that will add a static `Page X of Page X` in the footer? I will try this when im back in the office! I'll come back to mark as answer if its working. Thanks

Comment: Hello Lisa, Thanks for following up. I don't think I explained my problem statement very well. You code will add the `Page X of Page X` to the excel sheet. However, when I PDF the Workbook.. it will display for example `3 of 4` & `4 of 4` (as they are the 3rd and 4th pages of the PDF; instead of `1 of 2` and `2 of 2` as shown in excel. I will update OP with some pictures, will hopefully make things clearer. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Calico, I've edited my answer. The First page number should be set to 1 instead of Auto in Page Setup. That should do the trick.

Comment: sorry for the late reply! Worked perfect, thank you so much!